# How to retain request values in controller by hitting address bar with enter

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have developed Spring MVC web application. On page refresh jsp form values are properly going to controller working fine.

But if you select address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> `request.Parameter("name")` returning `null`. How to handle this case?

Note: Working fine for <kbd>F5</kbd> but causing problem on hitting browser bar with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you submit form, your browser use the [POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) method to send data.
When you hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, your browser resend data using previous HTTP method (`POST` in our case). But when you go to page via address bar, your browser use `GET` http method and don't send form value to the server.